# donot allow to go back after he logged in when pressing browser back button

Tags: php, html

a.php
here i save my state as logged in when i log in i go to b.php so when i try to go back to a.php it checks my state to direct my to b.php again if my state is logged in

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['login_state'];
?>
<?php
if($_SESSION['login_state'] == "loged in")
header("location:b.php");
?>
<html>
<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="b.php">
username :<input type="text"/>
</br>
submit :<input type="submit"/>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

b.php
here i have the link with a function when i press the link logout i call the function to change my state to loged out and direct my to a.php so when a.php checks my state it is not loged in so it will not direct me to b.php again.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function logout()
{
<?php
$_SESSION['login_state']="loged out";
header("location:a.php");
?>
}
</script>
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['login_state']="loged in";
echo $_SESSION['login_state'];
?>
<html>
<body>
<a href="#" onClick="logout()">logout</a>
</body>
</html>
```

i want to prevent the user by showing an alert ( do you want to log out or do you want to save you work before leaving this page ) how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve because of your cumbersome english...

You can't mix javascript and php together in your logout() function. But there's a solution:

1. make new file called "logout.php"
2. put your javascript logout()-function contents into it
3. Then fix your html:
   `<a href="logout.php">logout</a>`

And then, your original question. You can use **.onbeforeunload**:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  return 'Do you want to log out or do you want to save you work before leaving this page?';
};
```

Remember that the return text is not supported in all browsers.

Comment: sorry for my heavy English brother , all i wan to say is after some one login he goes to the home page then if he go to the previous page by pressing browser go back button he will be logged out , i just want to prevent this ( when you login to fb try to go back to login page , but you cant you stay logged in until you logout) thank you

Comment: You can put, say, ajax request(get php script) to the onbeforeunload function.